# Is there a recourse against UPS for not delivering packages on time?

Tags: united-states, texas, competition, shipping

I have a "new" address and ZIP code that appears to confuse UPS and consistently causes them to delay delivery of packages to me.

I've tried filing complaints with UPS itself, but to no avail: I tried talking with their local dispatcher but they still don't do much other than help finally locate and deliver the individual missing-package-of-the-week.

As a consumer, I don't even get to select which carrier the merchants I buy from will use so, as far as I'm concerned, UPS has a sort of monopoly here.

I've tried filing a BBB report, but it appears that BBB doesn't concern itself with requests for compensation other than refunds.  I would like to make some sort of punitive claim against UPS, even if it is just symbolic.

What recourse do I have against UPS for their negligent service to me?

Comment: There is no recourse because there is no privity of contract. Your recourse lies with the merchant.

Answer (score 6):

Private carriers typically (and UPS in particular) only have a contractual obligation to the person who pays to send the package.  Unless you're the one directly paying UPS to deliver the package *you have no legal recourse* because you're not a party to the "contract of carriage."

It does seem like you're suffering due to contractual and operational failures of UPS, but your recourse is against the merchant you paid for the goods, because you also paid them for delivery.  The merchant has recourse against UPS under their contract if they want to pursue it.

*Legally*: UPS does not have a monopoly on shipping, and their contractual duty is only to *their* customer.  The best you can do is encourage those from whom you purchase to aggressively claim against UPS for delays, and to use other carriers when possible.

Comment: Right. It's also worth noting that unless you chose a service like 1 or 2-day delivery, the carrier has absolutely no obligation to deliver a package "on time" - delivery estimates are just that, estimates.

Comment: But this doesn't really work in practice.  The merchant clearly doesn't have much interest to pursue this issue here, since for all they know, the address indeed may be wrong.  There should be some way for me to enforce an action here.

Comment: @cnst - I know and agree.  But _law_ is almost certainly not the answer to this sort of problem.  There are other ways to apply pressure to a company and/or to seek their help, given that we live in a _vaguely_ meritocratic/profit-oriented/free-market society.  You might get some practical advice for dealing with this sort of problem at http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cnst Not all problems fall within the realm of law. Sometimes, the solution is "shop elsewhere." That said, keep in mind that a potential claim against the merchant is independent of their claim against the shipper (for instance, if Fedex gives a package to USPS and USPS screws up, Fedex is liable to their customer whether or not they go after USPS)

Comment: So, I'm supposed to sue the merchant for UPS claiming my ZIP Code is invalid?  Shouldn't, then, UPS be a party to the suit, too?

Comment: @cnst: Lawsuits are a last resort, and rarely practical for routine commercial disputes.  If you contract with a merchant for delivery of goods by a certain date then your terms of service with that merchant should outline your recourse for failures.  For consumer mail-order commerce the easiest approach is to pay with a charge card and make a charge-back if the merchant doesn't satisfy its obligations.  If the merchant contracts with other parties to satisfy its obligations you are not normally a party to those sub-contracts.  This is the legal reality.  But other practical solutions exists.

Comment: @feetwet, but doing a charge-back is impractical -- it would bring one back to square one, except for the time wasted, which won't be returned or compensated, plus one'd have to acquire the goods in person, likely having to spend more time and money again; this would hardly be the resolution anyone would be happy with.

Comment: So, what's the practical resolution here?  They've even ended up mis-delivering my packages to different businesses at an entirely unrelated ZIP-Code and address than the one I specify.  Am I supposed to send a package to myself, or to open an account with UPS, and make sure a vendor I buy from would ship a package to me through my account, such that I'd have standing?  Perhaps there's still some sort of letter I could write to them asking for a symbolic 100$ compensation for these issues, for them to signify that they're taking this issue seriously and will fix it sooner than later?

Comment: @cnst: Again, law isn't really going to help you here.  You can certainly write demand letters without any legal justification, and that might help get the attention you want.  There is an art to writing, calling, and complaining effectively, but that's too big a topic to cover here.  Note also: Even if _you_ were the shipper you might not have a satisfactory claim for delayed and/or misdirected delivery: you should check UPS's contracts if you want to take that approach..

Comment: When they shipped my package to the wrong city, then further returned it as "refused", I wrote a letter to my vendor with all of the information, and telling them I would support a claim against UPS, this worked.  UPS called me to verify that I had not received the package, and the vendor got their money back for the shipment.  But it took some doing to figure out what to do and how to do it.  So yes, the shipper has the right to file a claim against UPS for not delivering the package properly.