# Is a (UK) retail company obliged to compensate their customer if the package was lost or stolen during international shipping?

Tags: international, consumer-protection, shipping

I ordered shoes from a UK based company, to be delivered in the US. It turns out the package was delivered in a different state over 500 miles from the delivery address I provided. Incredibly, the package was also signed as received by someone at delivery, so it was stolen from me.

After figuring this out with the company, their customer service blamed it on DHL and simply stopped answering my emails. I was hoping for a compensation of some sort, such as store credit or a full reimbursement.

Since I took advantage of a free international shipping deal, my understanding is that the company paid DHL for the shipping, so said company should be in a position to file a claim with DHL in order to resolve this. They haven't, nor do they seem to intend to do anything at all.

Do I have any legal recourse, or am I stuck with "threatening" them that they have lost my business forever?

(Additional information: the value of the package was 150+ USD.)

Comment: Is your question [not a duplicate of this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1037/10)?

Comment: Not quite, because I took advantage of a free shipping deal. The shipping cost is thus on the company, not me. This means they should be the ones filing a claim with DHL, which they haven't. I guess my question is how do I motivate them to resolve this. Will edit to reflect that, thank you.

Comment: The shipping is almost always contracted by the shipper, even if they pass the cost through to you.  Please read the answer and comments to the question I linked, and [also see this linked question](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1806/10).

Comment: My take-away from the answer to the question you linked is that DHL has a duty to their customer, which is the company I purchased from, and that I can only encourage that company to file a claim against DHL. But the other linked question has an answer saying the loss of the package is between DHL and me. So which is it? Sorry if it should be obvious, I am new to all this.

Comment: No, you have to read carefully.  In Germany it *appears* a private-party purchase puts the onus on the purchaser.  Even there, however, when the purchase is from a business, "the business bears the risk of shipping."  I think this question is a duplicate, but since you're having trouble finding the practical answer, it is: *Dispute the charge with whatever intermediary processed the payment*.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your patience. I will mark this as duplicate and figure out how to motivate the company at the lifehacks stackexchange.